# What is best: Create,hide,show new UIView or Create, show and remove UIView in Swift?

Tags: swift, performance, memory, uiview

I make use quit often of panels (`UIView`) to let the user interact. I am wondering what is the best way:

1. create the panel at the beginning of the viewDidLoad, then hide it until it comes in use, show it and hide it again until the next time it is needed

or

2. create the panel on the moment it is needed and after use remove it from view again. Next time it is needed create it again

Would method 1 consume a lot more memory and/or would it be much faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always go after the principle *[YAGNI - You aren't gonna need it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)* and this applies here in my opinion. Don´t create a bunch of stuff that you might not need. Create the views when you need them and then remove them when you´re done with them. **So go with option 2.**

Comment: You are right, many panels will be just used at first usage, but after a while no more or less, thanks